# I was bombarded by downvotes because I didn't find answer satisfying

Tags: support, downvotes

Recently I asked a question on Stack Overflow, and I didn't find the answer satisfactory. So I have chosen to leave the question open. But when the user who posted the answer asked me if I found it useful, I politely explained how it does not address the issue.

But immediately after that all my questions from the past started getting downvotes. I am sure everyone will agree that it's not fair for someone having a better score to go around downvoting my previous questions. How do I revert the unfair downvotes?

Comment: That obsessive serial downvoter knows what they're doing, because they wait 24 hours before downvoting more questions. Try following [this advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed/212339#212339) and [contact](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) SE personaly

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks Alon, the downvotes are actually so well timed.. Three downvotes every 24 hours. I am afraid I am going to lose all the score I have built up on SO.

Comment: Don't be - Contact them. From my experience, they are responsive and willing to help (Although I faced different issue, but they solved my problem). And as you probably know, an upvote of an answer will cancel 5 downvotes on other answers ;)

Comment: @NickDiv I've seen your flag - have you referred contact to the team already?

Comment: Side note: at current rate you need team of several sockpuppets voting on your questions to eat all you reputation over about a year... It is somewhat hard to do in a way that noone will notice...

Comment: To the downvoters here: note that this is done by *someone who **knows** what s/he is doing*. Technically, it is *not* a duplicate, because the canonical answer is "Don't worry. There is a system in place which will pick this issue up ..." but in this case the downvoter seems to be aware and quite deliberately avoiding it.

Comment: @RadLexus that was just the first paragraph. The rest of the answer seems to be applicable in this case: *"flag one of the posts for moderator attention using the "other" option and explain what happened"*.

Comment: @AlonEitan I have contacted them and also raised a flag. Thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: @JonClements Yes I have informed the SO team and hopefully they will look into it.